# is there a way to assign variable name by another variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create 4 variables (`ref`)

Here is my way to do it;

```
const ref1 = useRef()
const ref2 = useRef()
const ref3 = useRef()
const ref4 = useRef()
```

However, in some other components, the number of `ref` is going up.

So, I want to create a more dynamic way to create `ref` and have it return;
`ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4...`

My brief idea is to use `Array.from()` with a specified length and a callback function that returns `useRef()`

```
[ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5] = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => useRef())
```

However I can't figure out how to link up the `i` so that I have a array of `ref<i>`

```
[ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5] = Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => useRef())
```

Comment: This may break the rules of hooks?

Comment: Why not simply use an array to contain your refs in the first place? `const refs = new Array();  for (i=0;i<whatever;i++) {refs[i] = useRef()}`

Comment: Can you please clarify what you meant by "what rule and what hooks are you talking about"? I'm not sure I understand your question. Would you mind rephrasing it or providing more context? Thank you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox A react component must have always the same number of hooks between re-renders. If the refs quantity is constant, I think that it will work.

Comment: You're going to have to _actually_ explain "I want to create a more dynamic way to create ref" by giving a concrete example of when this makes sense, because without context, it doesn't. And include what those refs are being used _for_ because the very first solution is "make those things their own components" so each one of those manages their own ref.

Comment: Using an array for useRef is definitely an option. Thank you for sharing this alternative approach!

Comment: Those ref is going to place into different child components. I dont understand why the purpose of those refs for is important...Probably i missed sth, Isnt it they are for reference no matter what? Would you kindly clarify it? In addition, The context is about controlling the display of those children

Comment: @DanielBeck you can't conditionally use hooks

Comment: @Mulan his code example doesn't have conditional hooks.

Comment: @TKoL running a hook in a loop is a conditional hook. `for (i=0; i<whatever; i++) …` the condition is `i<whatever`. if `whatever=0` the hook runs zero times, if it is greater, the hook runs more times. it's a conditional hook and it's not allowed.

Comment: @Mulan as long as the `whatever` is constant, then it's effectively not conditional. The reason you don't want hooks to be called conditionally is because you have to guarantee that hooks are called the same number of times, in the same order, every time your functional component runs. If `whatever` is constant, then the hook will always run the exact same way, in the same order, the same number of times, every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot use hooks conditionally**. That includes using them in `if` statements, loops, or inside of callbacks. Hooks can be composed of other hooks, but all `use*` calls must be declared at the top-level of your component. For more info, see [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) in the React guide -

- ✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a [function component](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component).
- ✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a [custom Hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks).
- Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.
- Do not call Hooks after a conditional return statement.
- Do not call Hooks in event handlers.
- Do not call Hooks in class components.
- Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to `useMemo`, `useReducer`, or `useEffect`.

So you want an array of multiple refs? Simple, Use a *single* ref to an array! We can use `onChange` for each `<input>` to set the corresponding index in our array ref. <kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to verify in your own browser -

```js
function App({ count }) {
  const refs = React.useRef(Array(count))
  const setRef = (k, v) => refs.current[k] = v
  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(refs.current)
  }
  React.useEffect(() => console.log("render!"))
  return <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    {Array.from({length: count}, (_, key) =>
      <input
        key={key}
        onChange={e => setRef(key, e.target.value)}
        placeholder={key}
      />
    )}
    <button children="submit" />
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App count={5} />)
```

```css
body::before { content: "fill in some values and submit"; }
input { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you want an actual array of refs, that is still possible by creating your own ref-compatible objects, `{ current: … }`. In the demo below, you can see how our refs can be used in the `ref` attribute of the inputs. Instead of responding to `onChange`, the `onSubmit` callback extracts the current value from each `<input>`. <kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to verify in your own browser -

```js
function App({ count }) {
  const refs = React.useRef(Array.from({ length: count }, _ => ({ current: null })))
  const onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(refs.current.map(e => e.current.value))
  }
  React.useEffect(() => console.log("render!"))
  return <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    {Array.from({length: count}, (_, key) =>
      <input
        key={key}
        ref={refs.current[key]}
        placeholder={key}
      />
    )}
    <button children="submit" />
  </form>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App count={5} />)
```

```css
body::before { content: "fill in some values and submit"; }
input { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I apprecaite it. but what is the difference between using const [ref0, ref1, ref2] = Array(length).fill(useRef()) and const refs = React.useRef(Array.from({ length: count }, _ => ({ current: null })))
 ?

Comment: `Array(length).fill(useRef())` will insert the **same** reference to all indexes. Updating any index will simultaneously update every other index. `Array.from(…)` constructs a new array using a mapping function, where a **unique** `{current: null}` is inserted into each index.

Comment: thanks for clarifying it. I dont quite understand between ref={refs.current[key]} and what we usually have "ref={refs}" ..... say refs.current[1] is {current:null} at the moment.... how this json {current:null} hold the value of input?

Comment: ohh, or the essence of ref actually is { current: null }

Comment: correct, the essence of a reference is an object with a single mutable current property. `useRef` guarantees you will receive that same object for each render. updating the `current` property does not constitute a state change and will not re-render the component.

Comment: may i ask why you delete const [ref0, ref1, ref2] = Array(length).fill(useRef()) > is it problematic?

Comment: yes, i only had it there to test that it was in fact broken. i never intended to leave it on the answer :D

Comment: why is it? actuyally i used that code and failed too. want to know why

Comment: I already described at length above why the `Array.fill(…)` technique fails.

Comment: I get it finally, but just want to know how react could know that it is a conditional hook? i mean how react detect that there is a loop / code that may make it conditional hook

Answer (score 1):

Several comments mentioned [the rules of hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) but didn't elaborate on the significance.

Much of the internal implementation of hooks requires that a component references exactly the same hooks, exactly the same number, in exactly the same order. Think of it as the price of entry. That's why the rules specify that hooks can't appear in conditionals or loops.

It's not clear what you're trying to do by having some indeterminate number of refs in the same component. Maybe you can achieve it in a more Reacty way by introducing a subcomponent, with one ref in each subcomponent.

If though you're just looking for a way to store a collection of persisted values, perhaps instead of creating an array of refs, you could create a ref that contains an array. You could even make the array contain "ref-like" objects suitable for passing as component `ref` properties:

```js
  const arrayRef = useRef(
      Array.from({ length: 3 }).map(() => ({ current: null }))
  ).current;

  return <>
    { ["a","b","c"].map((id, index) =>
       <div ref={arrayRef[index]} key={id}>{id}</div>) }
  </>
```

A similar approach also works if you *really really* want to keep the variable names for some unspecified reason:

```js
  const [ref1, ref2, ref3] = useRef(
      Array.from({ length: 3 }).map(() => ({ current: null }))
  ).current;

  console.log(ref1.current);

  return <div ref={ref1}/> /* etc */
```

It's difficult to advise further without knowing what you're hoping to achieve with this array of refs, but in any case breaking the rules of hooks isn't the way to go about it.

Comment: Could you plz clarify why useRef(
      Array.from({ length: 3 }).map(() => ({ current: null }))
  ).current; but not simply const [ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5] =  new Array(5).fill(useRef()); ? why this way problematic? if not, why better?

Comment: To be clear – if you're creating "exactly 5 references" (or exactly 55, or exactly 555 ...) then it's not a problem to call `useRef` in a map, although various linting rules might complain about it. It does have what we might call a "code smell" though, it's a weird thing to do. The last example there is to illustrate that because `useRef` just maintains a reference to some blob of data between component renderings, you can use it _once_ to persist as many values as you like. There are likely to be some incidental performance gains but that's just gravy.

Answer (score -1):

You can set multiple variables to the same value by:

```js
var a = b = c = 2; // a = 2, b = 2, c = 2
```

but I don't think it would work in this case as each useRef needs to be a new one.

In an array you could:

```js
[a, b, c] = Array(3).fill(2); // a = 2, b = 2, c = 2
```

if you want to use an index you can:

```js
[a, b, c] = [...Array(3)].map((e, i) => i); // a = 0, b = 1, c = 2
```

and you can put any function in the map

e.g.

```js
[ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4] = [...Array(4)].map((e, i) => generateRef(i));
```

as other users have said it may be better just to store all these refs in an array.

```js
const refs = [...Array(4)].map((e, i) => useRef(i));
```

This would create an array which 4 refs each initially being 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively.

Comment: but i dont want to have a useRef with value by 1,2,3,4.... i want refs1,refs2.... and got the name assigned manually